# Does $K \cong K_0$ and $F \cong F_0$ imply $[K : F] = [K_0 : F_0]$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ and $K_0$ be two isomorphic fields and let $F$ and $F_0$ be two isomorphic fields such that $K / F$ and $K_0 / F_0$ are two extensions. I have furthermore that $K_0 / F_0$ is monogenic and his degree is $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Can I state that $[K : F] = n$? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What does *monogenic extension* mean? Is it the same as [*simple*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension)? As in a single generating element. In other words $K/F$ is monogenic if and only if there exists an element $z\in K$ such that $K=F(z)$?

Comment: Yes, a monogenic extension means that it is finitely generated only by one element.

Comment: Is there something missing about the relation of the extensions $K/F$ and $K_0/F_0$? Otherwise let $K=\Bbb{Q}(x)$, $F=\Bbb{Q}(x^6)$, $K_0=F_0=\Bbb{Q}(x^3)$. They are all isomorphic, $[K_0:F_0]=1$, $[K:F]=6$?

Comment: -1 I see no effort or thought; even though counterexamples are so plentiful and easy to construct, especially in view of your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873250/constructing-a-new-monogenic-extension-of-fields).